# How to change web content without affecting background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, css-animations

I have a website with the background having a particle effect that is animated using CSS.

Whenever you switch pages the particles are disrupted and reset. Is there any solution that allows me to change only the web content of the page and not affect the background? Technically the particles are an element.

[image: Picture of Particles]

Comment: can you show how it works?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the animation not to be interrupted, you need to prevent the page from reloading, and update the data inside the page using the [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) + [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). This can be done both on pure JS or using React ([React-Router](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)), Vue ([Vue-Router](https://router.vuejs.org)) libraries, etc.
In fact, you need to make a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) out of your website.